# DoCmd.TransferDatabase Error 3125: "___ is not a valid name."

Tags: ms-access

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", _
Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Data\ABC_Back.accdb", acTable, _
"import_aels", Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Data\Archived.accdb"
```

This is not a valid name. Make sure it is a valid parameter or alias name, that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation, and that the name is not too long. (Error 3125)

Does it not like the underscores?

The correct code is -

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", _
Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Data\Archive.accdb", acTable, _
"import_aels", "import_aels" & Format(Now, "_YYYY-MM-DD_HHMMSS") & ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fifth argument to `TransferDatabase`, *Destination*, is the name that the exported object (Table, in this case) will have in the destination database (specified by the third argument, *DatabaseName*). Your *Destination* argument looks like a file specification and is not a valid table name because table names cannot contain a period (`.`).

Comment: That was it.  Is there a way to make it move the data from the back end rather than creating a link?

Comment: @Kaw4Life One way to do it might be to use a make-table query something like `SELECT * INTO [path\Archived.accdb].[tablename] FROM [import_aels]`.